# What is the best combined of jquery version and jquery ui version?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

As my question title, i want to know the best combined of jquery version and jquery ui version?

Comment: "Best" is a subjective term, and one of the things it's subject to is what you're trying to achieve. "Best" questions are almost always off-topic for SO.

Comment: I dont think there is any official plugin for which combines both jQuery anf and jQueryUI , you just need to refer jQuery official site,http://api.jquery.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By jsfiddle, the best combined of jquery version and jquery ui version is:

```
jquery < 1.x (edge) => jquery ui 1.8.5
jquery 1.72 => jquery ui 1.8.18
jquery 1.83 => jquery ui 1.9.2
jquery 1.91 => jquery ui 1.9.2
jquery 1.2.0 => jquery ui 1.10.3
jquery 2.x(edge) => jquery ui 1.10.3
```

Answer (score 1):

*In general*, and subject to various caveats, the latest stable version of each is the "best" one to use. (Or on rare occasions, the latest stable version of jQuery UI and the latest version of jQuery it's been tested with, in case that's briefly a dot rev behind. The jQuery UI website will always tell you what the latest version of jQuery it's been tested with is.)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery-ui is a library that requires jQuery, the best jQuery-ui would be the one that you built that includes only the parts that you need, the best jQuery would be the latest one that is compatible with the jQuery-ui library that you chose.